# How do you integrate HTML page with JWT Node JS Auth?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jwt

I have created a node.js application and have successfully define a protected route with token. I can run it via POSTMAN.  I am trying to understand how then do I integrate this into a HTML page and login and call out the protected route to display on a HTML page instead of using POSTMAN. I am creating a html website and want a user login and then they can access certain link in the page.

My app.js

```
app.post('/api/posts', verifyToken, (req, res) => {  
jwt.verify(req.token, secretKey, (err, authData) => {
  if(err) {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  } else {
    res.json({
      message: 'Post created...',
      authData : authData,
      
    });
    
  }
});
```

});

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
// Mock user

```
var email=req.body.email;
var password=req.body.password;

const userdata = {
   
 email: email,
 password: password
}

console.log(userdata);
jwt.sign({userdata}, secretKey, (err, token) => {
  res.json({
    token
  });
});
```

});

my HTML

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Portal API Test site</h1> 
        
        <form action="/api/posts", method="POST">
            <h2>Getting from Header</h2>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit", >
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need a local server for your static HTML to be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i will suggest you to use at least a small framework to make the work easier for you such as react, svelte ... Otherwise you can jQuery to do that.

To log in a user, you need to save the JWT in cookie or localStorage. That's not a very difficult task but remember to set the header of every requests on protected routes with the Bearer Token

You can follow this example: https://github.com/chaofz/jquery-jwt-auth/blob/master/index.html

```
localStorage.setItem('token', yourTokenresponseFromExpress);
```